# Where can I find the old tutorial.tex from csquotes package?

Tags: tutorials, csquotes

I was researching a `csquotes` problem and I came across a [reference](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=5444) to `tutorial.tex`. The file is no longer included in `csquotes` and I can not find any reference to the removal in the `csquotes` changelog. Where can I find `tutorial.tex`?

Comment: You can find the file here: https://www.sys.kth.se/docs/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/csquotes/tutorial.tex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code can be found on this website: https://www.sys.kth.se/docs/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/csquotes/tutorial.tex

I can't post it here because it's too long so I put it on pastebin.com:

http://pastebin.com/YV8zAeKa

Comment: Thanks. I put a copy on gh in case anyone is ever looking for the file.

https://github.com/dfc/csquotes-tutorial.tex

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of (or looked for) this file before, but what I suspect you should look at instead is `csquotes.cfg`: after the `\endinput`, there follows a long section providing examples of how to use the package.  It is full of examples, explanations, and even some potentially useful shorthands that you may find useful.  (If you want to try them, you need to move them above the `\endinput`.  Even if this tutorial file is still kicking around, I recommend you take a look at the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Google showed me some sources, where one can still find it: search for[`csquotes tutorial filetype:tex`](https://www.google.com/search?q=csquotes+tutorial+filetype%3Atex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: All of those are dead links...

"Note: you requested the material at a path /macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/tutorial.tex that doesn't exist. This is the closest directory."

Comment: @dfc Did you visit the link I mentioned in my comment above?

Comment: @dfc No! There are more places found, and I downloaded it myself from one of the shown sources.